# How to change the style of text in one element in a list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the style of the text of an item in a list, for example of "yellow":

- white
- orange
- yellow
- blue

Is there a way of doing it from CSS without using JavaScript. THe element is not necessarily the penultimate in the list. 
ANy pointer is much appreciated

Comment: Changing the style is what CSS is made for. Please clarify the actual issue you are having and add your current code that's not working

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Yes, it is possible to style an item in a list.

Comment: My kids found [this site](http://www.lissaexplains.com/css.shtml) really helpful getting them started learning CSS. They are 9 and 12, respectively.

Comment: Hi all, sorry it wasn't very clear and I should have posted my code. I clarified further down to Drew who understood what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nth-child:

```
#example:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

assuming a list such as:

```
<ul id="example">
<li>white</ul>
<li>orange</li>
<li>yellow</li>
<li>blue</li>
</ul>
```

There is no CSS selector based on element content.  You could use jquery:

To set a css property value:

```
$("#example li:contains('yellow')").css('background-color','yellow');
```

or if you want to assign a css class:

```
$("#example li:contains('yellow')").addClass('makeYellow');
```

where the css for the example immediately above would be something like:

```
.makeYellow { background-color:yellow; }
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, that's exactly what I thought of doing, however, the list is generated on the fly and some other list items can be added to the current one, so if I address the "yellow" element like this, if I add one more item, the "blue" one will have a different background. I was thinking whether it is possible to check the text content of the list item and if it is equal to "yellow" then apply a different style.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an id or class for the list item that you want to set the colour. Then in your stylesheet, you just set the colour for that id or class. Here's an example:

```
<style>
    .highlight {color: yellow}
</style>
<ul>
    <li class="highlight">yellow</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It was just make it clear. It seems like the OP doesn't have a grasp on classes and ids, so why complicate it ;)

Comment: Completely understand clarity, the code just makes me cringe to see!  :)

Comment: Haha fair enough. I changed it just for you :P

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use id selector for this purpose,you should modify you html code and add an id to that item in the list.

```css
#yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
        <uL>
  <li>white</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li id="yellow">yellow</li>
  <li>blue</li>
</ul>
```